# How to set the accessibilityIdentifier on a React Native component?

Tags: react-native, accessibility, xcode-ui-testing, react-native-ios, uiaccessibility

I’d like to add an `accessibilityIdentifier` to a React Native component, so that I can use Xcode’s UI testing to navigate around my app.

Is there a way to specify the `accessibilityIdentifier` (*not* the `accessibilityLabel`) for React Native?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add an `accessibilityIdentifier` on React Native components (View, Text, Image...) using the [testID](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view.html#testid) property. This gets added to the component as a `accessibilityIdentifier` on iOS. 
**Note** that it doesn't work on custom components.

Here's an example:

```
<TextInput
  placeholderTextColor="#dddddd"
  style={[styles.main, styles.textColor]}
  placeholder="Add a new todo item"
  onChangeText={this.handleInputChanges}
  value={inputValue}
  testID="addToDoItem"
/>
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer @Naishy. What if one wants to put identifiers in custom components ? Can he/she use any of the accessibility identifiers from here: https://necolas.github.io/react-native-web/docs/accessibility/ or not ?

Comment: @GeorgePligoropoulos I don't see the relation between react-native and react-native-web here

Comment: @Naishy this is not true, especially for Android where it is more complexe than that due to React native bug, if you add `accessible={true}` and/or `accessibilityLabel="something"`, you can have a bunch of undesired effect. A proper answer would explain to everyone how they are related and what are solution for each case.